# Openvpn does not route traffic

Tags: vpn, openvpn, vps

I am trying to set up a vpn on a ramnode vps, to route all my phone traffic trough it.
I can connect to the vpn, but my ip (whatsmyip.org) stayed the same after connecting. From this I concluded my traffic wasnt going trough the vpn.
After searching for a solution I added

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

to my server.config. Now when connecting to the vpn, I cannot access any sites. It will try to connect for a while, and then give a "Server not found"
I am using openvpn on a debian 7 vps, and trying to connect from an android smartphone with OpenVPN Connect

OpenVPN log, from starting, connecting from mobile and then going to a site
http://pastebin.com/saAAgPLY

Comment: Check your log and see if you have "WARNING: 'comp-lzo' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='comp-lzo'" in there, or anything about comp-Izo - mismatched settings can cause this problem

Comment: comp-lzo is present in both configs, and I see no error messages from it @Sam3000

Comment: Ah, so much for the easy fix then, can you access and post the server log for us, that should show any errors, although you may need to change the "verb" (verbosity level) in the server.conf file first to get use able information, try a value of 6 if you can't see any errors just yet

Comment: @Sam3000 http://pastebin.com/saAAgPLY

Comment: Thanks, I noticed I can't connect to my own VPN from an android mobile, despite desktop computers connecting fine, perhaps mobile platforms require specifics that I'm not aware of. Aside from that, there are packets being dropped in the logs, it might be worth using TCP as that should prevent dropped packets causing issues, but I feel like there's more at work here

Comment: I fixed my problem, ill type up the full solution when home. It had to do with my vps being openvz, which required a different iptables rule

Comment: Great news, well done